# TurnKey Django -- how to upgrade Django to 1.4

Tags: django, ubuntu, upgrade, ubuntu-10.04

I cannot find a good source of information on how to upgrade Django to 1.4 on TurnKey Django (based on Ubuntu 10.04).  I did not worked at Unix machine for a long time and I am a bit lost.  Some IRC channel?

Comment: On what version are you currently?

Comment: @Paragon: It is difficult to say as I started with the downloade machine (I think it was Django 1.1), later installed somehow Django 1.3.1.  Now I tried `python setup.py install` for Django 1.4 but `django.get_version()` still returns `1.3.1`.  I am fairly good in Python, but I am not good concerning Linux and Django. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am having a hard time finding an official source with version information, it seems to me that the latest Django release for TurnKey Linux is (as of Dec. 2011) at most version 1.3.1.

Check out [this mail archive question](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg129620.html) and click through the threads for more information. They discuss setting up the latest version of Django for TurnKey Linux using tools such as virtualenv to ensure that you are able to continue to use older (outdated) packages if need be.

Comment: Thanks.  Actually, it was me who asked in the archive question.  The Django 1.3.1 was not the part of the TurnKey Django distribution.  Thanks anyway, and have a good time.

Comment: @pepr Hah, maybe I should have guessed. Wish I could have been more of a help.

Comment: I have finally solved it using a brute force.  I did remove all Django related packages (directories) that I have found via `updatedb`/`locate django`.  Then I have installed the latest Django via `pip install django`.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to install django 1.4 in a virtual environment.

First, install virtualenv (if its not installed already `sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv`)

Then, install django 1.4:

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages django_1_4
$ source django_1_4/bin/activate
(django_1_4) $ pip install django
(django_1_4) $ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:44:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.get_version()
'1.4'
```

After your comment, I have another suggestion. Since this is a single purpose machine, you can simply upgrade the *global* version of django on your machine.

First, to avoid conflicts, *uninstall* django if it was installed from apt:

`apt-get remove --purge python-django`

Then, since you already installed `python-virtualenv` from above, you can do this:

`$ sudo pip install -U django`

This will upgrade (or install) django to the latest version available to the global site packages directory.

Then you can do the same `import django` and then `django.get_version()` and it should return `1.4`.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I will look at the virtualenv.  However, the machine is a virtual machine on its own, and it was created only for the purpose (single apache, single Python, single Django, no need to separate the environment).  But I have met the recommendation for the virtualenv, and I will definitely look at it.  Thanks again and have a good time. ;)